# how to find ip address in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ip-address

Is it possible to get the ip address of server's private ip? i.e., local ip of users who are all accessing my site.

i tried using

```
request.remote_ip
request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
request.env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://checkip.amazonaws.com/'))
request.env['REMOTE_HOST']
request.remote_addr
request.env['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
using socket
```

but it shows same ip for all the users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your server running public or is it just running on your local networK?

Comment: I don't think you question is specific to Ruby 1.8.7, but Rails, which reached EOL a long time ago.

Comment: @Codextremist: local network..

Comment: Is the website behind a web server or proxy?

Comment: @Kris: mentioned the ruby version im using

Comment: Do you want the IP of users PC on the local network, e.g. 192.681.0.10?

Comment: @Kris: exactly.. that's what im asking

Comment: Are you running the app with production env?

Comment: @Kris:  yes.. with production env

Comment: Maybe you could use something like [wireshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/10784/can-download-wireshark-for-ubuntu-linux) to see the HTTP connections and what IP address they originate from.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `request.remote_addr`.

The code you used `request.remote_ip` 
is used in rails, not in Ruby.

Hope it helped.